# Are Q&As allowed that specifically point to the use of a particular product or service?

Tags: discussion, support

So for instance if I have created a really great product for Ubuntu which is fully free and in my PPA, and my product would help a lot of people, would it be considered promotional spam if I were to post a Q&A where I ask a question, and then provide my product as the solution? Or would that by looked upon badly?

Comment: related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13715/should-i-keep-an-eye-on-spam-like-answers-about-free-software-or-why-do-people

Comment: Don't leave us hanging in a vacuum, tell us what it is so we can make an informed opinion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking generally, if...

- It's relevant; it answers the question(s), and
- You disclose your interest, and
- You don't *plaster* the site with it...

... We have no problem with it. If somebody has a useful and helpful thing to share with us, I think we can accept that sometimes the people posting it might occasionally have a vested interest in that.

I'd look much less favourably on something —and someone— if they set up a question just to answer it with their product. While self-answering is generally seen as fine, you stretch its external usefulness when you start doing it to promote your own stuff.

And we start handing out suspensions like free candy if you start doing that from different accounts. AstroTurfing is toxic. Recommendations **must** be based on personal views.

If you suspect anything of falling foul of these guidelines, flag it up and we'll have a look.

Comment: So what if lots of people were having a problem, but there was no real fix for the problem, so I posted a question asking directly about that problem (as nobody else had already), where I answered with my solution, which may have been a link to my PPA which an explanation of use of the software etc to fix the problem?